# How to get ALBUM_ART in android using MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI?

Tags: android, xml

I am creating a music app in which I need to show singer name song title and etc but what I want is to get image for that particular song too I have tried many things but could not get properly

```
Here is the code

 ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
                Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

                if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {

                    int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                            (MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                    int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                            (MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                    int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                            (MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                    int album = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                            (MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
                   int album_art = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                            (MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);

                    do {
                        long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                        String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                        String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                        String albumName = musicCursor.getString(album);
                        String albumArt = musicCursor.getString(album_art);

                        songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, albumName, albumArt));

                    }
                    while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }

I tried but while debugging log cat showing this error 

       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lenovodesktop.musicplayerapplication/com.example.lenovodesktop.musicplayerapplication.PlayList}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
                at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
                at com.example.lenovodesktop.musicplayerapplication.PlayList.getSongList(PlayList.java:69)


        Here I am using cursor for fetching information of song available in sd card
    everything is woking fine but when I tried to fetch images for song it gave me above error
```